# react table select rows - programmatically select rows based on input props

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

I have created a react table with select rows following [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/row-selection?file=/src/App.js:556-603).
I'm trying to modify it so that when the data loads, the corresponding checkbox is either checked or unchecked based on the row data's `included` value. The value doesn't seem to be recognized and when I check/uncheck a row the onChange console.log event isn't being fired. What am I doing wrong.

[Heres my Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-stitch-5g3zt?file=/src/IndeterminateCheckbox.js)

DATA

```
[
  {
    systemId: 13,
    deqId: "25007",
    facilityId: 6487,
    sourceId: "WS002",
    sourceName: "GROVE SPRING",
    flowRate: 461,
    flowUom: "GPM   ",
    included: true
  },
  {
    systemId: 13,
    deqId: "25007",
    facilityId: 4742,
    sourceId: "WS004",
    sourceName: "WELL #1",
    flowRate: 1100,
    flowUom: "GPM   ",
    included: true
  },
  {
    systemId: 13,
    deqId: "25007",
    facilityId: 4743,
    sourceId: "WS005",
    sourceName: "100 W (WELL #2)                         ",
    flowRate: 800,
    flowUom: "GPM   ",
    included: true
  },
  {
    systemId: 13,
    deqId: "25007",
    facilityId: 4744,
    sourceId: "WS007",
    sourceName: "NORTH (WELL #3)                         ",
    flowRate: 900,
    flowUom: "GPM   ",
    included: true
  }
];
```

INDETERMINATE CHECKBOX

```
const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(
  ({ indeterminate, checked, name, ...rest }, ref) => {
    const defaultRef = React.useRef(checked);
    const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;

    React.useEffect(() => {
      resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
      resolvedRef.current.checked = checked;
    }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate, checked]);

    return (
      <>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          ref={resolvedRef}
          checked={checked}
          name={name}
          id={name}
          {...rest}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
);
```

REACT TABLE

```
function ReactTable({
  columns,
  data,
  handleCheckboxSelection,
  handleCheckboxStateChange
}) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    footerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    selectedFlatRows
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data
    },
    useRowSelect,
    (hooks) => {
      hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
        // Let's make a column for selection
        {
          id: "selection",
          // The header can use the table's getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps method
          // to render a checkbox
          Header: (
            { getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps },
            handleCheckboxStateChange
          ) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
          // The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
          // to the render a checkbox
          Cell: ({ row }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox
                name={row.original.sourceId}
                onChange={(row) => console.log(row.original)} //not firing
                checked={row.original.included}
                {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()}
              />
            </div>
          )
        },
        ...columns
      ]);
    }
  );

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.slice(0, 10).map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          {footerGroups.map((group) => (
            <tr {...group.getFooterGroupProps()}>
              {group.headers.map((column) => (
                <td {...column.getFooterProps()}>
                  <b>{column.render("Footer")}</b>
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tfoot>
      </table>
      <button onClick={() => handleCheckboxSelection(selectedFlatRows)}>
        Save
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

TABLE IMPLEMENTATION

```
const MyDataTable = ({
  data
}) => {

const handleCheckboxSelection = (array) => {
    console.log(array.map((d) => d.original));
  };

  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Source ID",
        accessor: "sourceId"
      },
      {
        Header: "Source Name",
        accessor: "sourceName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Flow Rate (GPM)",
        accessor: (d) => {
          return d.flowRate ? numberWithCommas(d.flowRate) : "";
        }
      }
    ],
    []
  );
  return (
    <ReactTable
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      handleCheckboxSelection={handleCheckboxSelection}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The props you added to IndeterminateCheckbox are being overwritten. `row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()` returns an object:

```
{
   onChange: function,
   checked: Boolean,
   title: String,
   indeterminate: Boolean,
   style: Object
}
```

which overwrites your properties.

The correct way to do what you want to do would be to use
[initialState.selectedRowIds property](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useRowSelect#instance-properties) from the useRowSelect API.

Map your data to their `included` values, then add that array to the initialState as selectedRowIds. In ReactTable.js:

```
const selectedRowIds = data.map((d, ind) => d.included)
const { 
  // etc 
} = useTable(
  {
    columns,
    data,
    initialState: {selectedRowIds}
  },
  //etc
  ...columns
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to refresh your Table.
you can use `useState`.
example : you can add `onClick={this.mychange}` to your save Button.

```
mychange = async () => {
  
    this.setState({
        List: //the new List Data
    })
    
  }
```

and dont forget the Constructor.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      List: anyList,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).